# Effective Linear Regression for datasets with missing values in explanatory (independent) variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, linear-model, missing-data

I have an **econometric dataset of countries** consisting of features such as `GDP, GDP per capita, internet penetration rate, life expectancy, poverty etc`. There are a lot of **missing values** (20-30% depending on the feature). 
The task is to come up with a linear regression model that predicts poverty with decent accuracy. However, since most entities contain at least one missing value in explanatory variables the output of the model is usually NA. 
The question is whether there are linear regression algorithms that deal with this problem. If not, then what other ML techniques should I consider (such as SVM, KNN etc)?